# How create your custom auth system in django?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models

I want to create login, register and other pages for authentification, but without using User model and not extending AbstractUser or AbstractBaseUser(this is necessarily). How can I do these type of things in django? I'm asking because I can't find any sources with answers for this question, and also I'm just started using django. In all sources which I found they still using User model or django's auth system.

Comment: Your question is far too broad. Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: In short, you can't use features of django's auth system(like using `request.user.is_authenticated`) and you have handle things manually.